# How do i print only decimal points in C++ without set limit but with setting precision dynamicly?

Tags: c++, precision

```
double n;
cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
cin >> n;
cout<<setprecision(4)<<n;
```

I want to set floting point precision dynamicly i. e. at runtime instead of static value 4.

Comment: Do you mean, how to use a value for the precision that is chosen at runtime, instead of a hard coded “4”?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Formatted precision of floating value has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with "dynamic memory allocation". What does "dynamic memory allocation" mean to you?

Comment: Clearing questio again. I have to take an input number (double) from user and after that i want to cosider only float part of it to find mean and variance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
double n;
cout << "Enter a number : "  << endl;
cin >> n;
cout << "Enter required precision : ";
int precision;
cin >> precision;
cout << setprecision(precision)  << n;
```